# Make turtle change variable if conditions are met

Tags: netlogo

I have to breeds, `breed1` and `breed2`, and only `breed1` can change a variable `var` if members of `breed2` are close enough `radius 4`. However, my code does not work, see below.

This is part of a code which breed1 will execute:

```
  let x min-one-of other breed2 with [ var >= 6 ] in-radius 4 [ distance myself ] ;check whether there is one (or more) members of breed2 with a value of or above 6 of var
  
  ifelse (x != nobody) [ ;if there is one
    ask one-of breed2 in-radius 4 with [ var >= 6 ] [ set var var + 1 ] ;change value
    [right random 360 forward 1] ;else walk random
```

My idea is that breed1 checks for members of breed2 in its vicinity (radius 4) if there is one or many, it shall change one of them with a value above 6 of a given variable (var).

However, the above code does not change the variable var. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a bracketing error - your then code is not ended before starting your else code. But you also have an efficiency issue because you are constructing the nearby turtles twice. Once you have x, you can simply use it. So fixing that and the bracketing error:

```
ifelse (x != nobody)
[ ask x [ set var var + 1 ] ]  ; x changes value
[ right random 360 forward 1 ] ; the asking turtle moves
```